# Symfony 3.4 / createQueryBuilder does not work if andWhere() is used (ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder, symfony-3.4

I am currently trying to build a simple query to find a user by its username:

```
namespace Swenso\IntranetBundle\Repository;

use Swenso\IntranetBundle\Entity\Employee;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method Employee|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Employee|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Employee[]    findAll()
 * @method Employee[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class EmployeeRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Employee::class);
    }

    public function findByUsername($value)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->andWhere('e.username = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->orderBy('e.id', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
            ;
    }
```

Running this code results in the following error:

```
Attempted to load class "Composite" from namespace "Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Composite"?
```

If I leave out the `andWhere()` the query runs well...

If somebody could help we that would be great!

BR wucherpfennig

Comment: Does using `->where()` work? `->andWhere()` implies a composite condition. It works as you'd expect it to current versions, but that may not always have been the case.

Comment: andWhere will work just fine.  The error message indicates you have a Composite constraint on your entity which was improperly defined.  So the error is actually coming from the validator, not the query.  Are you using a form?  In any event, double check your Composite constraint/validator class and maybe post the code if you can't find the problem.

Comment: @janh no, I do get the same error

Comment: @Cerad Honestly I do not know. The code above is used to find the user which tries to login to easyadmin. Actually I do not find any validator of any sort in my code... And yes the username is coming from a form

Comment: Not very familiar with EasyAdmin.  A Composite constraint is a Symfony class which contains multiple constraints and then applies them one after another.  Presumably you have something like this going on somewhere in the EasyAdmin's generated code.  Maybe searching for Composite might help but maybe not.

Comment: @Cerad I did but I am not finding anything. Honestly I do not think that it is directly related to easyadmin because the error is coming from the authentication side... the only change coming to my mind is a recent `composer upgrade` but honestly I do not know where to start looking for changed packages...

Comment: php version?  Use 7.4.4 if possible.  Some of the earlier versions had some preloading issues resulting in mysterious errors.  And of course clear the cache.  Stepping through the code might help.  Just grasping for straws here.  If you kept your older composer.lock file then maybe try reverting.

Comment: Well currently I am running on 7.1.33. on the production serve this code still works since all changes happened locally. Also reverting all updates did not do the trick...

Comment: your code looks correct, can you verify that class actually exists in vendor folder \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Composite.php ? also sharing your composer.json might help

Comment: @kaznovac yes this file existed and playing around with it yielded in even more errors.

SOLVED:

Honestly I do not know what finally helped. Whether it was the up and downs with composer, going through the code without changing effectively something or finding out that we had issues setting up the right authentication / user loading process which would not explain why the repository was not able to be loaded correctly...

Anyway thank you all for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error before on same symfony version, and for this after query builder I couldn't do an `->andWhere()` because you didnt started yet the `->where()` conditional statement.

First always need to start the conditon with ->where() and after you can concatenate using more `->andWhere()`/`->orWhere()`.

On doctrine [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html#working-with-querybuilder) they put a note that we can use andWhere without setting where before.

Also try to look on this documentation page from symfony to check if the repository class is well build https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/repository.html maybe the etends service you are calling is not loading the good Entity Manager.

I hope this works.
Cheers

Comment: The first part of this answer is just plain wrong: you always start with andWhere.  Always could.  Try it.  The second part about entity managers is just a pure guess unless you can explain a connection between a wrong entity manager and the 'Composite' constraint  error.